# How i fix the syntax error in the "while" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I´m making my code of a "bookshelf" for my books, and i´m making the condition that says: "while x variable is smaller than y variable, continue, else, break", but python says that in the line, there´s a syntax error, but, i´m not understanding where´s the error.

I tried re-runnning the code, verifying the spaces of identation, and such, but for me, there´s nothing wrong, and for python, there´s a syntax error.

```
def lista()
    cadastrados = 0 
    livros = int(input("Quantos livros você deseja cadastrar?")
    while cadastrados < livros:
        print()
        linha()
        print()
        print()
        título = input("Put the title of your book: ")
        autor = input("Put the writer of your book: ")
        gênero = input("Put the gender of your book: ")
        cadastrados += 1
        if cadastrados >= livros:
            break
```

I expected the loop of the questions, and adding the numbers to the "cadastrados" variable, and if the number hits the limit, the "while" loop would stop, but the actual results is "**invalid syntax**" highlighting the "while" statement

Comment: missing parenthesis on line 2 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a closed parenthesis

```
livros = int(input("Quantos livros você deseja cadastrar?")
```

should be

```
livros = int(input("Quantos livros você deseja cadastrar?"))
```